# How could I split the result in a column into two separate columns in python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

this the col that I need to split in python

[image]

I've tried this but it back with an error

```
events["top_element_info"]= events["top_element_info"].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True)
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOlHk.png)

Comment: please describe the error in the question as well

Comment: It seems it is python dict, what is the error log?

Comment: added snip of the error

Comment: yes need the key to be col name & value to be row value

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the ids as your first column and points as the second one, you can do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"top_element_info": [{'id': 123, 'points': 20}, {'id': 124, 'points': 30}, {'id': 125, 'points': 40}]})
for col in ['id', 'points']:
    df[col] = [x[col] for x in df['top_element_info']]
```

Comment: got this error TypeError:
"TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-cf58e10b66a0> in <module>
      1 df = pd.DataFrame(events)
      2 for col in ['id', 'points']:
----> 3     df[col] = [x[col] for x in df['top_element_info']]

<ipython-input-83-cf58e10b66a0> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 df = pd.DataFrame(events)
      2 for col in ['id', 'points']:
----> 3     df[col] = [x[col] for x in df['top_element_info']]

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: I'm using python 3.9 and pandas version 2.0.3 and the code snippet above works just fine. Maybe try to update your pandas version to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to split the string into two and store it into two columns. The issue is you are trying to split the string into two columns by assigning expand to True but trying to store it into a single column.

Try:

```
events["top_element_info_id"], events["top_element_info_points"] = events["top_element_info"].str.split(",", n = 1, expand = True)
```

Comment: same error this  is the column type "Data columns (total 11 columns):
top_element_info         0 non-null float64"

Comment: @Momo can you try converting the column "top_element_info_id" into string using the following statement: events["top_element_info"] = events["top_element_info"].apply(str)

Answer (score 0):

after combining the solutions I've reached this

```
events["top_element_info"] = events["top_element_info"].apply(str)
events["top_element_info"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r"'id':",value=r'')
events["top_element_info"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r"'points': ",value=r'')
events["top_element_info"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r"}",value=r'')
events["top_element_info"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r"}",value=r'')

events[['top_element_info_id', 'top_element_info_points']] = events['top_element_info'].str.split(',', 2, expand=True)
events.head()
```

and it solved now thanks for all :)